# How to Increase SharePoint 2013 Document Library file name length limit more than 256

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I transfered my file serve files to the sharepoint 2013 database but now I am facing issues with file name length limit which is 256 characters.

Is there any workaround to increase this Character limit for the files and folders?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get around the limitation, but there is a tool that Microsoft gives you to shorten files and folders, and if it can't, will rename the file/folder to something like "Invalid". https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2933738

Alternatively, you can write a PowerShell script to rename any file/folder to a lesser limit, possibly by cutting off/deleting the characters that goes over the 256 character limit.

Comment: Just curious regarding this tool "easy fix". Is it open source, or are there any open source libraries similar to it that you are aware of? I am thinking about getting it to work with my managed code.

Comment: No, but you could write your own. It wouldn't be too hard to traverse through files and folders and rename them if they have more than 256 characters.

Comment: Just for file name length, yes, it's not too hard. But I was thinking about broad usage for file/folder names, resulting URL length, invalid characters and duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

> The total URL length limit is 256 characters - SharePoint won't allow
>   you to upload a file or folder if the total URL length exceeds that.

**Note**: There is no workaround to increase this Character limit for the files and folders.