# How to short url in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url, shortcut

there is a limit of 255 chars on Url link. 
Is there a way to short the link? (not using internet service)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing OOTB available, but there are third-party tools to achieve this.
https://www.sharepointshorturl.com/

There is an interesting article about how to bypass
http://www.ixitapp.com/Blog/Post/20/How-to-bypass-SharePoint-URL-path-length-restrictions.  I am sure there might many others articles, but one of the recommendations you will get is avoid folder structure and use metadata. Since there is no workaround OOTB to change the limit. Some discussion [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176520/how-to-increase-sharepoint-2013-document-library-file-name-length-limit-more-tha).

For SharePoint online, this has [recently changed](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2017/05/09/new-maxpath-limits-in-sharepoint-and-onedrive/) to 400 characters so this may roll to SharePoint 2013/2016 in the future.